# Unsigned int to byte

Tags: java, unsigned, signed

I'm trying to create a custom inputstream. My problem is, the read() method returns an integer from 0-255, but I need to convert it to a byte, decrypt it, and convert it back to an integer. How?

I need something like:

```
InputStream in = ...;
OutputStream out = ...;

int unsigned = in.read();
byte signed = unsignedIntToSignedByte(unsigned); // from -128 to 127
... // Editing it here
outputstream.write(signedByteToUnsignedInt(signed)); // from 0 - 255
```

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Whatever you want to do can be accomplished, but probably not the way you think you need to do it.  Explain what you're trying to accomplish, especially the _"edit it"_ part.

Comment: You want to do what now?

Comment: This is unlikely, after all you can just manipulate that value as an `int`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a stream for a specific encryption. The encryption class can't work with ints, only with bytes. That's what I want to do it in the "edit it" part. @JimGarrison

Comment: Just cast it to `byte` then

Comment: Whatever you want to do you can do in `int` and then convert back to `byte` at the end.  Until you explain EXACTLY what manipulation you want to perform we cannot help you. Java operates internally on `int`, not `byte`.

Comment: Note that it would usually be more efficient to manipulate a whole chunk of data at a time: call `read(byte[])` (remembering to take note of the return value, as that's the number of bytes *actually* read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that creating your own encryption is unsafe, and assuming you're doing it "just for fun" and don't think in any way that what you're doing is secure, you really don't need anything special...

```
int i = in.read();
byte b = (byte) i;
byte e = encrypt(b);
out.write(e);
```

would be the basic approach, assuming `byte encrypt(byte b)` method which does the "encryption". Checking for end-of-stream, exception handling, performance considerations (you don't want to perform things 1 byte at a time) etc. have been left out from this example.

Comment: It's not my encryption, it's an open-src encryption which doesn't provide stream support, but I need stream support.

Comment: @Florian They you have asked the wrong question. Ask about encryotion sterewam support.